# Reference request: PDE of the form $(\Delta - |u|^2)f = F(u)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

I am interested in equations of the form
$$(\Delta -|u|^2)f = F(u)$$
where $F$ depends on $u$ and preferably on its derivative, too. $u$ is supposed to be given and $f$ the unknown. More precisely I am interested in how to obtain a priori bounds on $f$, i.e.
$$ \|f\|_X \leq \|(\Delta-|u|^2)^{-1} F(u)\|_Y$$
Of course, if we were to replace $(\Delta-|u|^2)^{-1}$ by, say, $\Delta^{-1}$ we could use something like Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev to obtain bounds which is not possible if you take the term $|u|^2$ into account. If you can help me out with references on this kind of equation I would be very grateful.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: seeing as $u$ is given, isn't this just a linear PDE?

Comment: Looks very linear to me indeed!

Comment: @LeoMoos I know it is linear but I need to know how to estimate the RHS (say $|u|^2$ is known to be in some $L^p$ for $1\leq p \leq \infty$ in terms of the LHS. The usual Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality doesn't apply here, right?

Comment: @Jakob: Have you checked the books of Han-Lin or Gilbarg-Trudinger for an answer to your question? Off the top of my head, the answer to your question might depend on whether $u \in L^p$ for some $p > n$. Could you be more precise about the specific estimate you are looking for? I also think there might be a typo in the inequality you state, should it be $\lVert f \rVert \leq C \lVert F(u) \rVert$?